# Spring Batch commit-interval dynamic value

Tags: spring-batch

I have a `Spring batch job` with standard reader , writer and processor

I have a simple requirement like below :

1)Whatever records reader reads all should be passed to writer by processing through processor

2)My reader reads records by SQL query 
 So if reader reads **100 records** , all should be passed to writer at once

3)If it reads **1000 records** , all 1000 should be passed at once

4)So in essence , **commit-interval** is dynamic here and not fixed.

5)Is there any way we can achieve this ?

**EDIT :**

To give more clarity , in sprint batch , commit-interval plays a role of chunk oriented processing 
E.g : if chunk-size = 10 , reader reads 10 records , passes one record 1 by 1 to processor and at commit-interval (count = 10 ) , all records are written by writer .

Now what we want is dynamic commit-interval. Whatever is being read by reader , all will be passed to writer at once

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "should be passed to writer **at once**"? Can you explain what are trying to achieve without referring to Spring Batch?

Comment: I have edited question to give more clarity

Comment: At which moment you will know commit-interval then? Only when performing `SELECT` query?

Comment: @Atul Could you please provide your solution how did you achieved to set commit-interval dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved using chunk-completion-policy property.

```
<step id="XXXXX">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="XXXReader"
                       processor="XXXProcessor"
                       writer="XXXWriter"
                       chunk-completion-policy="defaultResultCompletionPolicy">
                </chunk>
            </tasklet>
        </step>

<bean id="defaultResultCompletionPolicy" class="org.springframework.batch.repeat.policy.DefaultResultCompletionPolicy" scope="step"/>
```

Also we can write custom chunk-completion policy

see this post

[Spring Batch custom completion policy for dynamic chunk size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390602/spring-batch-custom-completion-policy-for-dynamic-chunk-size)